# Django- Imagekit Not Creating Thumbnails

Tags: python, django

I want imagekit to return users pictures as thumbnails when they upload and still keep the original picture. But the thumbnail picture should be the one it will return. I've read imagekit docs, yet no success. It's not returning thumbnail images. It will only return the actual size of the image uploaded by users. I've been searching for tutorials on how to make this work, but I can't find one that dig into this topic. How can I make imagekit return uploaded pictures as thumbnails? I'm using imagekit v2.0.

Models

```
       class Meek(models.Model):
          user=models.ForeignKey(User)
          title=models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
          address=models.CharField(max_length=200)
          city=models.CharField(max_length=200)
          state=models.CharField(max_length=200)
          main_view=models.ImageField(upload_to="photos",blank=True, null=True)
          side_view=models.ImageField(upload_to="photos",blank=True, null=True)
          pub_date=models.DateTimeField()
          thumbnail=ImageSpecField([Adjust(contrast=1.2, sharpness=1.1),ResizeToFill(50, 50)], image_field='main_view', format='JPEG',options={'quality': 90})
          thumbnail=ImageSpecField([Adjust(contrast=1.2, sharpness=1.1),ResizeToFill(50, 50)], image_field='side_view', format='JPEG',options={'quality': 90})
          def __unicode__(self):
              return self.title
```

Views

```
            def findme(request):
                extra_data_context={}
                if request.method=="POST":
                    form=MeekForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
                    if form.is_valid():
                       data=form.cleaned_data
                       newmeeks=Meek(
                          user=request.user,
                          pub_date=datetime.datetime.now(),
                          title=data['title'],
                          main_view=request.FILES['main_view'],
                          side_view=request.FILES['side_view'],
                          address=data['address'],
                          city=data['city'],
                          state=data['state'])
                      newmeeks.save()
                   extra_data_context.update({'MeekForm':form})
              else:
                 form = MeekForm()
                 extra_data_context.update({'MeekForm':form})
              extra_data_context.update({'Meeks':Meek.objects.filter(user=request.user)})
              return render_to_response('postme.html',extra_data_context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Template

```
       {% for Meek in Meeks.object_list %}
               {# posted only this because, I'm only having problem with images. #}
           <p><img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}/{{Meek.main_view}}"/> <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}/{{Meek.side_view}}"/> </p>

         {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

Model:

```
class Model(models.Model):
    image_1 = ProcessedImageField([Adjust(contrast=1.2, sharpness=1.1), ResizeToFill(500, 370)], upload_to=generate_image_filename_1, format='JPEG', options={'quality': 90})
    thumbnail_1 = ImageSpec([Adjust(contrast=1.2, sharpness=1.1), ResizeToFill(83, 78)], image_field='image_1', cache_to=generate_cache_filename, format='JPEG', options={'quality': 90})
```

View:

```
def thumbnail(request, pk):
    thumb_pk = pk
    instance = Model.objects.get(pk=thumb_pk)
    return render_to_response('thumbnail.html',{'instance': instance},context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Template 'thumbnail.html':

```
# show the tumbnail

<img alt="thumbnail" src="{{ instance.thumbnail_1.url }}" width="83" height="78">
```

Comment: I have more than one imagefield I want to upload. any idea of how I will make all images uploaded return as thumbnail?

Comment: Thanks so much! I've gotten it. All I did was to make changes to my thumbnail like this: thumbnail_1=ImageSpecField(details) 
thumbnail_2=ImageSpecField(details)

template:

<img src="{{Meek.thumbnail_1.url}}" >  I did the same for the second thumbnail.